# Facebook: How do I detect the user's current permissions?

Tags: facebook

I need to know if the permissions of a facebook user by the access token.

I've been searching and searching for quite some time and I can't find how.

How can I get it programmatically using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the getLoginStatus function. One of the properties of the object it returns is "perms" which is the permissions list.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Comment: Thanks, but how can we do it programmatically using C#? Sorry, I should have been more precise.

Comment: To me it seems like this is no longer possible. I only get the 'status' and 'authResponse' but there's not perms inside. Maybe it has been removed?

Comment: the authResponse object contains what you need. That contains a userID and accessToken.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer (although I takes some work to grasp it) seems to be this SDK.

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Use it.

Since I had not specified that I wanted a C# solution and Bret Baisley's answer proved to be very useful anywany, I consider his answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found this PHP solution very handy:

```
if (array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0])) {
    // Permission is granted!
    // Do the related task
    $post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'Hello World!'));
} else {
    // We don't have the permission
    // Alert the user or ask for the permission!
    header("Location: ".$facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream")));
}
```

took it from here, also with FBQL version:
http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-user-has-certian-permission-facebook-api/22/